# can't draw image on canvas after clearRect

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

i am having some trouble with the following code. Essentially this is wrapped up in an image uploader. So once the uploader completes its callback the following code gets executed:

```
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
var logoImage = new Image();
logoImage.onload = function() {

   c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   c.drawImage(logoImage, 0, 0, 200, 300); // i've simplified this call...
}
logoImage.src = "/path/to/" + fileName;
```

So this works the first time. But I expected that it would work subsequent times as well. So when another image is uploaded, the canvas is cleared and that image is drawn. Instead what happens is that the canvas is cleared but no further drawing takes place...

Any ideas?

Comment: Try posting an example via http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: The code you posted looks fine so we'll need more information. if you add `console.log("over 'er")` just before the `c.clearRect`, does it display in the console each time?

Comment: Seems that there is some issue in filename! Check your code where you are getting the image and alert filename to check if it is correct or not!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

replace the

```
 c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

with:

```
canvas.width=canvas.width;
```